# SCADA reading from MariaDB: Error in Syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access, mariadb, scada, wonderware

We have a SCADA System (Intouch). It had a Access .mdb database file on the client PC, which was defined as System DSN (Windows ODBC).

What I'm trying to do is to migrate the whole DB thing to MariaDB, running on remote server. I have already a running server, the connection from the SCADA PC to the server is up an running and it is added as system DSN in ODBC, using the MariaDB ODBC connector. I was also able to export all the data from Access to the Maria database, using Access's native export to ODBC database, so all my data is in Maria.

The Problem: The SCADA cannot read ot white anythig. In the scada's log i get SQL Syntax errors (forgot to mention, that the scada uses SQL). Thanks in advance!

Update: 
It's old fashioned WindowMaker application, not Archestra, thus the SQL Functions are used. I've even changed the ODBC connector from Maria to mySQL
Today I've made some logs. Here the error:

```
"SELECT Checksum, (rest deletet by me.. is too long).... FROM Stp WHERE ProgNr=1and StpNr=0"

[37000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.3.22-MariaDB]
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'StpNr=0' at line 1 (1064)
```

Comment: How are you doing your SQL? Are you using InTouch's SQL functions within WindowMaker or are you calling functions within ArchestrA graphics (via the aaDBClient library or calling .NET's functions)? Can you provide a few samples of the errors you're getting from the SMC Logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the review of your update it looks like its just a plain ol' syntax error.

What you provided:

```
SELECT Checksum, (etc)... FROM Stp WHERE ProgNr=1and StpNr=0
```

The logs complain of syntax by `StpNr=0` but your problem is immediately before that where you haven't put a space between the `AND` and the `ProgNr=1` command.

Correct syntax would be:

```
SELECT Checksum, (etc)... FROM Stp WHERE ProgNr=1 and StpNr=0
```

---

In my personal experience the WindowMaker SQL functions are extremely clunky to work with (especially with the 131 char limit on message tags). You can usually help yourself out by Logging your Query then trying it directly in your database.

Comment: Found it myself yesterday :) But, thanks alot anyway. Always the obvious mistakes get overlooked.